# How to use custom functions within a Underscore template?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I have a helper JavaScript file but I can't use it in my template: it throws an error saying that the `helper` is not defined.

Example code:

```
<img alt="" src="<%= helper.isURL(images[i].small) ? images[i].small : '/img/' + images[i].small %>">
```

I tried embedding some raw javascript block with `isURL` but I still get the same error.

```
<script>function isURL() {}</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Underscore templates can use plain JS. You can expose anything you want in the *context* object that the compiled template function uses.

In the following example, I created a simplified `Helper` object which is passed to the compiled template function in the extended `data` object.

```js
var data = { test: "value" },

    // simplified mock of the helpers
    Helper = { isUrl: function(){ return true; } },
    
    // compiled template function
    template = _.template('result: <%= Helper.isUrl(data.test) ? data.test : "default" %>'),
    
    // the same data, now including the Helper
    extendedData = _.extend({ Helper: Helper }, data),
    
    // rendered template as a string
    rendered = template(extendedData);

console.log(rendered);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Anything public is also available by default.

Here, I use a public variable and the `join` Array's prototype function.

```js
window.test = "public data";

var data = { arr: ['test', 'test2'] },
    template = _.template('arr: <%= arr.join(", ") %>\ntest: <%= test %>');

console.log(template(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```